# Facebook: Added custom app to page but it doesnt show up as a custom tab

Tags: facebook

I've added my app to my page but it doesnt show up as a tab. Why?

See attached image FBapp.png which shows all settings. When I click 'Edit Settings' for the TicketWise app I get notification: "There are no settings for this application."

Here's my Facebook application: https://apps.facebook.com/ticketwise/?fb_page_id=208837722506615
(never mind the scrollbars for now)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you view your page, underneath the image/logo area there is a list of tabs.  Depending on how many tabs you have, at the bottom there will either be a link for "EDIT" or "MORE".  If "MORE", click to see the full list of tabs and the EDIT link.  When you click "EDIT" you will be able to drag and drop the tabs to reorder them and place your application near the top where it will be visible by default.

For your other query:

> When I click 'Edit Settings' for the TicketWise app I get notification: "There are no settings for this application."

Settings pages are something you have to create separately if your app requires it.  They are a page hosted on your server, that defines parameters to be used on the tab page view of the app.  You can define the page in your application settings using the "Page Tab Edit URL" field.

Comment: But that doesnt explain why my tab isnt visible on my page at all right?

Comment: Have you given a Page Tab URL in the settings?  Your screenshot cuts off just before that field.

Comment: No hadnt done that, so now I have added this (but still no luck):

Page Tab Name:Ticketwise
Page Tab URL:http://www.ticketwise.nl/
Secure Page Tab URL:https://www.ticketwise.nl/
Page Tab Edit URL: <empty>

Comment: It might be worth removing and re-adding you tab now that you've assigned a page to it.  Be aware though that a tab has a max width of 520, so your site is going to get cut off.

Comment: Yes, thx! Tab is there...it shows an error now, but I can take it from here :)